# Load more post with AJAX

Tags: custom-post-types, ajax, javascript, rest-api

I have a simple post that i am using alipine.js to help me load post using AJAX.

So far it is loading my pages and changing the category if I click a filter button, this is all expected and working.

However I have updated my code to show more when click "load more button", this is not showing and giving no error.

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong ?

**Post page**

```
  <html>
<head>
     <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
     <script>
Alpine.data("filterPosts", (adminURL) => ({
    posts: "",
    limit: 6,
    total: null,
    category: null,
    post_type_js: post_id,
    showDefault: true,
    showFiltered: false,
    offset: 0,
    
    filterPosts(id) {
        this.showDefault = false;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.category = id;
        this.offset = 0; // <-- reset offset to zero
        this.fetchPosts();
    },
    
     loadMore() {
        this.loadingMore = true;
        this.offset += 10;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.fetchPosts(true);
    },

    fetchPosts(append = false) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("action", "filterPosts");
        formData.append("limit", this.limit);
        formData.append("post_type_js", this.post_type_js);
        formData.append("offset", this.offset); // <-- Add new data to the form

        if (this.category) {
            formData.append("category", this.category);
        }

    fetch(adminURL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
            if (append) {
                // Appends posts to the end of existing posts data
                this.posts = this.posts.concat(res.posts);
            } else {
                // Resets the posts data with new data
                this.posts = res.posts;
            }

            this.loading = false;
        });
    },
    
    getTotal() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("action", "filterPosts");

    fetch(adminURL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
        this.total = res.total;
    });
},

init() {
    this.getTotal();
}

}));
})
     </script>
     
   
</head>
<body>
    <div x-data="filterPosts('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>')">
<section <?php theme_section_attr_id() ?> <?php theme_section_attr_class('main-section js-posts') ?>>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading mx-0">
      <?php $before_title = get_sub_field('before_title');
      if ($before_title) : ?>
        <strong class="sub-title"><?php echo $before_title ?></strong>
      <?php endif ?>
      <?php $title = get_sub_field('title');
      if ($title) : ?>
        <h2><?php echo $title ?> </h2>
      <?php endif ?>
    </div>

      <div class="head js-posts-search-text">
        <?php if ($search_value) : ?>
          <h2 class="h5 fw-semibold"><?php printf(__('Showing results for “%s”', 'base'), $search_value) ?></h2>
        <?php endif ?>
      </div>
      
<!--alipne js dynamic post start-->
    <div class="has-filter row flex-md-row-reverse">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9 js-posts-holder">
            
        <!-- Posts Column -->
            <div x-show.important="showDefault" class="row cards-area js-posts-items">
                <!-- Default posts query -->
                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/posts-filter/default-query' ); ?>
            </div>
                <!-- Filtered posts -->
            <div x-show.important="showFiltered" x-html="posts"class="row cards-area js-posts-items">
            </div>
            <!-- Load More Posts -->
            
       <!-- Load More Posts -->
<div @click="loadMore()" x-show="total > (limit + offset)" class="text-center mt-12 pt-5">
    <button class="">
        Load More
    </button>
</div>
         </div>
            
        <!-- Filtered posts -->
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
             <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/posts-filter/filter-query' ); ?>
        <!-- Filtered end -->
         </div>   
    </div>
    </div>
<!--alipne js dynamic post end-->

</section>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**functions.php**

```
// the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_filterPosts', 'filterPosts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filterPosts', 'filterPosts');

function filterPosts()
{
    $response = [
        'posts' => "",
    ];
        // New args for an All Posts Query
    $all_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // returns all posts
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );

    
    $filter_args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );

    if ($_POST['limit']) {
        $filter_args['posts_per_page'] = $_POST['limit'];
    }
    
     if ($_POST['post_type_js']) {
        $filter_args['post_type'] = $_POST['post_type_js'];
    }

    if ($_POST['category']) {
        $filter_args['cat'] = $_POST['category'];
        
        // Get the total number of posts for the category
        $all_args['cat'] = $_POST['category'];

    }

    $filter_query = new WP_Query($filter_args);
    
    // New All Posts Query
    $all_query = new WP_Query($all_args);

    

    if ($filter_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($filter_query->have_posts()) : $filter_query->the_post();
            $response['posts'] .= load_template_part('/template-parts/posts-filter/single-post');
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;

    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}


function load_template_part($template_name, $part_name = null, $args = [])
{
    ob_start();
    get_template_part($template_name, $part_name, $args);
    $var = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $var;
}
```